# Implementing a simple state machine for use in JavaFx2.0 Game Framework

Tags: java, javascript, state-machine

I am building a simple game framework using JavaFx 2.  In the past, using AS3 and javascript, I could simply define my constants and code something like this(pseudo-code):

```
const BEGIN_STATE;
const END_STATE;
const PLAY_STATE;
```

and then inside my game loop use logic to change states as needed... BEGIN_STATE might become PLAY_STATE when the constant gets passed to a switchSystemState(stateConst) function.

```
switchSystemState
```

Since functions can't be passed about like variables in Java I really have no idea where to begin.

So hopefully someone out there can give me some insight into the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From a basic coding standpoint, while it is true that Java does not allow functions to be passed around as first class objects (as in JavaScript), it is simply a matter of passing around a reference to an instance of an object that holds the member function you wish to call.

It's very hard to completely visualize exactly what you are trying to achieve from your description, but I think you may want to define a static function, because a static function is defined one time within the runtime environment and may then be made visible to all the other sections of code that may have need to call the static function.

If you can provide a little more detail or a more structured description of what you are trying to achieve, it will make it easier to give you a specific answer or suggested path forward.